# Change back a state to previous value

Tags: reactjs, meteor, flux

Actually I have to questions but the main one is that once I emit a change and I catch it within componentWillMount to make a setState, how can I change that state back to it's previous value? I tried writing a setState on a componentDidMount but it throws a maximum stack call.

I'm also using mdl for the UI and I noticed that if I move across components, some features like the materialSnackbar function stops working. I don't know if it has something to do with the fact that i'm using react router and these components that are using these functions are props.children

Answer (score 0):

if you want to wind back the state of a component you will need to store it in a parent component in order to rewind. Currently in vanilla react there is no way to re-wind the internal state of a component without keeping track of it somewhere else.

so lets say you have the following components

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
    getInitialState() {
        return({
            stateHistory: [
                          { name: "foo" },
                          { name: "bar" }
                          { name: "baz" }
                          ],
            stateHistoryIndex: 0
        })
    },

    onRewind() {
        this.setState({
            stateHistoryIndex: this.state.stateHistoryIndex += 1
        });
    },

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
             <ChildComponent 
                 data={this.state.stateHistory[this.state.stateHistoryIndex]} 
                  handleRewind={this.onRewind}
              />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
    render()  {
        return(
            <div>
                Hi, my name is {this.props.data.name}
                <button onClick={() => this.props.handleRewind()}>Rewind</button>
            </div>
        )
    } 
}
```

as you can see, we'd need to store the state in a parent component and access it via an index which we can control via the child.